# MYSQL - Creacion de cursor para datatable con 3 tablas

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Quiero realizar una consulta con 3 tablas que me genere un cursor donde no repita la informacion de un mismo numero_pedido, ya que dificulta la lectura a los usuarios.

Este es el resultado que deseamos:
[image]

Pero al realizar la consulta con un select y left join, el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se desea es saber como poder eliminar esos campos (marron y amarillo) que se duplican para que la lectura o al momento de exportarlo a un excel sea facil su interpretacion para el usuario.

¿Esto se puede realizar con un SELECT y LEFT JOIN o se puede realizar mediante la creacion de un cursor que recorra cada registro y actualice los campos en blanco?

Aquí les dejo un script para la creacion de tablas y datos de pruebas.

```
  CREATE TABLE `tmp_guia` (
  `sguia_numero_pedido` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sguia_hoja_ruta` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `satencion_persona` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert tmp_guia values ("N001", "HB001", "JOSE PEREZ");
insert tmp_guia values ("N002", "HB002", "JAVIER SOLIS");
insert tmp_guia values ("N003", "HB003", "MARIA ROSARIO");

CREATE TABLE `tmp_guia_detalle` (
  `sguia_numero_pedido` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sguia_detalle_numero_item` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '001',
  `sproducto_codigo` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sproducto_descripcion` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nproducto_cantidad` decimal(5,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nproducto_peso` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `nproducto_costo` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert tmp_guia_detalle values ("N001", "001", "P01", "VACUNAS", 10, 23.40, 0);
insert tmp_guia_detalle values ("N001", "002", "P02", "CAJAS", 13, 23.00, 520.00);
insert tmp_guia_detalle values ("N001", "003", "P02", "CAJAS", 5, 00.00, 00.00);
insert tmp_guia_detalle values ("N002", "001", "P03", "CAJAS", 5, 6, 0);
insert tmp_guia_detalle values ("N003", "001", "P05", "CILINDROS", 42.25, 75, 52.20);

CREATE TABLE `tmp_guia_documentos_cliente` (
  `sguia_numero_pedido` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `scliente_tipo_documento_codigo` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `scliente_guia_numero` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values ("N001", "GR", "001-00001");
insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values ("N002", "GR", "001-00002");
insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values ("N003", "GR", "001-00003");
insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values ("N003", "GR", "001-00004");
insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values ("N003", "GR", "001-00005");
insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values ("N003", "GR", "001-00006");
```

Por mi parte seguiré viendo la manera de realizarlo pero cualquier sugerencia, se agradece de antemano.

Saludos

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Haz el [tour] (y de paso obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)) y lee [ask]. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta escribiendo los resultados obtenidos/esperados? Las imágenes son dificultosas de leer. Podrías incluso **resaltar** y _resaltar_ lo que actualmente está en colores en la última imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para éste caso podemos usar variables de usuario para ir detectando el cambio de grupo:

```
SELECT if( @grupo1 := (@sguia_numero_pedido = g.sguia_numero_pedido)
         , null
         , if( @sguia_numero_pedido := g.sguia_numero_pedido
             , null
             , g.sguia_numero_pedido
             ) 
         ) sguia_numero_pedido
     , if( @grupo1, null, g.sguia_hoja_ruta  ) sguia_hoja_ruta
     , if( @grupo1, null, g.satencion_persona) satencion_persona
     , if( @grupo2 := @grupo1 and (@sguia_detalle_numero_item = gd.sguia_detalle_numero_item) 
         , null
         , if( @sguia_detalle_numero_item := gd.sguia_detalle_numero_item
             , gd.sguia_detalle_numero_item
             , null
             ) 
         ) sguia_detalle_numero_item
      , if( @grupo2, null, gd.sproducto_codigo      ) sproducto_codigo
      , if( @grupo2, null, gd.sproducto_descripcion ) sproducto_descripcion
      , if( @grupo2, null, gd.nproducto_cantidad    ) nproducto_cantidad
      , if( @grupo2, null, gd.nproducto_peso        ) nproducto_peso
      , if( @grupo2, null, gd.nproducto_costo       ) nproducto_costo
      , if( @grupo3 := @grupo1 and (@scliente_guia_numero = gdc.scliente_guia_numero)
          , null
          , if( @scliente_guia_numero := gdc.scliente_guia_numero
              , gdc.scliente_tipo_documento_codigo
              , null
              )
          ) scliente_tipo_documento_codigo
      , if( @grupo3, null, gdc.scliente_guia_numero ) scliente_guia_numero
  FROM tmp_guia g
    INNER JOIN tmp_guia_detalle gd
      USING (sguia_numero_pedido)
    INNER JOIN tmp_guia_documentos_cliente gdc
      USING (sguia_numero_pedido)
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT @grupo1 := false
                      , @sguia_numero_pedido := null
                      , @grupo2 := false
                      , @sguia_detalle_numero_item := null
                      , @grupo3 := false
                      , @scliente_guia_numero := null
               ) v
```

El último `JOIN` es para iniciar las variables a utilizar.
Los grupos se forman a partir del número de pedido, número de item y número de guía, usando una variable para guardar el último valor de cada uno.

Las variables `grupo1`, `grupo2` y `grupo3` contienen un booleano que nos indicarán si estamos en el mismo grupo, es decir, el valor de grupo se repite.

Usamos `IF`s para aplicar la lógica simple: Si se repite el valor regresa null, de lo contrario, asigna el valor nuevo e inclúyelo en el resultado de la consulta.

Comment: Exactamente, ese sentencia emite el resultado que se requiere.